# How to set the value of the GridView bound field based on the condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I'm looking for a solution to bind a value to a column of a `GridView` control based on a condition.

Let's say I have a property:

```
public bool Perm
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Based on that property, I want to set the bound field to a particular value.

Here I'm getting a list:

```
List<MyObject> obj = myservice.GetData().toList();
```

`MyObject` has the properties `FullBankAcc` and `HiddenBankAcc`.

Based on the value of the `Perm` property, I want to display either one value or another:

```
if (Perm)
{
   // bind a column to a HiddenBankAcc
}
else
{
   // bind a column to a FullBankAcc
}
```

This is the `GridView` column:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Display the value based on a property" HeaderText="ABA"/>
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: Change `BoundField` to `TemplateField`, bind both `hidden` and `full` and set `visible` attribute accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure how to code it in the GridView. I now about TemplateField, but not sure how to code it in my particular example

Comment: Set `visible="false"` for one of them according to condition.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be add another readonly field to your MyObject class that wraps the logic you want and bind the column to that field.

```
    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get {
             if (Perm)
             {
               return HiddenBankAcc;
            }
            else
            {
               return FullBankAcc;
            }
       }
   }
```

Comment: The permission boolean belongs to the code behind file. I would really prefer some kind of way, where I use the logic in code behind, without modifying the existing object structure. That object already returns 2 types of fields for FullAccount and HiddenAccount

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to a `TemplateField` you can do it inline.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BankAcc">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("HiddenBankAcc").ToString()) ? Eval("FullBankAcc") : Eval("HiddenBankAcc")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or as Boolean

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BankAcc">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("FullBankAcc")) ? Eval("FullBankAcc") : Eval("HiddenBankAcc")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thank you, But, how would I do that based on the boolean value set in my codebehind file?

Comment: Updated my answer. Basically you cast or convert the Eval to the correct datatype

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean();` will raise Null-Reference-Exception if the DB field is `NULL`. Make sure to check for `NULLs` in case. Also, I would recommend to bound the value to a Label Control that will help you get it's value by finding the specific control and reading it's value.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create the function in your page's code behind

```
   public string DisplayValue(Perm)
   {
             if (Perm)
             {
               return HiddenBankAcc;
            }
            else
            {
               return FullBankAcc;
            }
   }
```

2.) Assuming the value of variable "Perm" is in your gridview's datasource, on the aspx page

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ABA">
   <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DisplayValue((bool)Eval("Perm"))%>' </asp:Label>
</asp:BoundField>
```